# mod_wsgi automatic code change reload - Runtime Error from monitor script

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

Here is the code from the mod_wsgi documentation:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import sys
import time
import signal
import threading
import atexit

try:
    import Queue as queue
except ImportError:
    import queue

_interval = 1.0
_times = {}
_files = []

_running = False
_queue = queue.Queue()
_lock = threading.Lock()

def _restart(path):
    _queue.put(True)
    prefix = 'monitor (pid=%d):' % os.getpid()
    print('%s Change detected to \'%s\'.' % (prefix, path), file=sys.stderr)
    print('%s Triggering process restart.' % prefix, file=sys.stderr)
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)

def _modified(path):
    try:
        # If path doesn't denote a file and were previously
        # tracking it, then it has been removed or the file type
        # has changed so force a restart. If not previously
        # tracking the file then we can ignore it as probably
        # pseudo reference such as when file extracted from a
        # collection of modules contained in a zip file.

        if not os.path.isfile(path):
            return path in _times

        # Check for when file last modified.

        mtime = os.stat(path).st_mtime
        if path not in _times:
            _times[path] = mtime

        # Force restart when modification time has changed, even
        # if time now older, as that could indicate older file
        # has been restored.

        if mtime != _times[path]:
            return True
    except:
        # If any exception occured, likely that file has been
        # been removed just before stat(), so force a restart.

        return True

    return False

def _monitor():
    while 1:
        # Check modification times on all files in sys.modules.
        for module in sys.modules.values():
            print(module)
            if not hasattr(module, '__file__'):
                continue
            path = getattr(module, '__file__')
            if not path:
                continue
            if os.path.splitext(path)[1] in ['.pyc', '.pyo', '.pyd']:
                path = path[:-1]
            if _modified(path):
                return _restart(path)

        # Check modification times on files which have
        # specifically been registered for monitoring.

        for path in _files:
            print(f'PATH: {path}')
            if _modified(path):
                return _restart(path)

        # Go to sleep for specified interval.

        try:
            return _queue.get(timeout=_interval)
        except:
            pass

_thread = threading.Thread(target=_monitor)
_thread.setDaemon(True)

def _exiting():
    try:
        _queue.put(True)
    except:
        pass
    _thread.join()

atexit.register(_exiting)

def track(path):
    if path not in _files:
        _files.append(path)

def start(interval=1.0):
    global _interval
    if interval < _interval:
        _interval = interval

    global _running
    _lock.acquire()
    if not _running:
        prefix = 'monitor (pid=%d):' % os.getpid()
        print('%s Starting change monitor.' % prefix, file=sys.stderr)
        _running = True
        _thread.start()
    _lock.release()
```

And here is the error I get:

```
[Thu Feb 23 18:46:27.482446 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 11279] Exception in thread Thread-1 (_monitor):
[Thu Feb 23 18:46:27.482617 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 11279] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Feb 23 18:46:27.482635 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 11279]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
[Thu Feb 23 18:46:27.482983 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 11279]     self.run()
[Thu Feb 23 18:46:27.483002 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 11279]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
[Thu Feb 23 18:46:27.483162 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 11279]     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
[Thu Feb 23 18:46:27.483177 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 11279]   File "/srv/flask_app/flask_app/monitor.py", line 66, in _monitor
[Thu Feb 23 18:46:27.483239 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 11279]     for module in sys.modules.values():
[Thu Feb 23 18:46:27.483263 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 11279] RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during iteration
```

This is the code I'm calling the monitor with (currently):

```
monitor.start(interval=1.0)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.dirname(__file__), topdown=False):
   for name in files:
      monitor.track(os.path.join(root, name))
```

I tried with the exact same code as the author suggested, but got the same error then as well.

I have no idea how to get this to work, as I can't see why this is a problem at all, what is changing in the sys.modules during iteration, and why?

I've tried changing what files to track, sometimes it works for one reload, sometimes it doesn't work at all. I have no idea what else I can do tbh. Seems to work best with a random filename like 'site.cy' as the author had in the default example in the mod_wsgi documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like making a copy of the sys.modules.values() works fine to iterate over.